# Backup Pro(ish) is exporting empty SQL files

Tags: ee2

I've just installed Backup Pro(ish). This is my first time using the addon, so the problem I'm having could very well be "user error. I have the database backup method set to "MySQLDUMP", unfortunately every time I perform a backup and export the database it's an empty file. I've tried the PHP backup method and this appears to work, but I would prefer to get the SQL file.

I'm running EE v2.6.1 and am using the Focus Lab master config. I'm not sure if that would have any affect on the issue.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Can you check phpinfo and see if your server has SuHosin enabled. I had a similar issue and it turned out that unfortunately Backup Pro doesn't work on servers with this enabled.